# Inbox Access when I don't have a red alert mark

Tags: support

I had an inbox alert (the little red circle) and clicked on the message to respond, but then the computer froze and I had to reboot.  Now, I can no longer access the message to find out what comment there was.  How do I check this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the StackExchange logo where you normally click for Inbox notifications, but you have no current notifications, it will open to the "hot questions" section.  To see messages, including older ones, you can click on "inbox" between "all sites" and "notifications".